# Get PROFILEID with IPN after subscription

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

When a user subscribe to my offer thanks to the subscription button, IPN returns the following informations :

- subscr_id
- txn_id
- payer_id
- payment_date
- residence_country
- etc...

After the subscription I need to use the [GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) method which require the folowing fields:

- METHOD
- PROFILEID

How can I get the PROFILEID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to call GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails API , please set "GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails" for variable METHOD, and data in "subscr_id" for variable PROFILEID in the API request.